# How to create a ANCS Mail and Call notification programmatically

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to find a way to create a ANCS (Apple Notification Center System) Mail (which includes Messages, SMS, Calendar and Reminder) or Call notification in my app running on an iPhone so that I can control the Mail and Call indicators on my smartwatch.

When my smartwatch pairs with my iPhone, my smartwatch then subscribes to the ANCS on my iPhone. Does anyone know a way to create and remove Mail and Call notifications programmatically?